# What is 「ケステンGチンキ」 a reference to?

Tags: translation, words, loanwords

This word/set of words/whatever it is popped up in something I am reading, and I cannot find any clue as to what it is referencing. The book is a taiko performer's biography, and this is the very last sentence of the introduction, where he is reminiscing about Sado Island and his deep connection to it.

The sentence in question:

> 真野湾沖に三二の漁火を数えた夜、ケステンGチンキをぬりながら・・・佐渡で

I know the beginning is something along the lines of "The night that I counted 32 fish-luring flames out on Mano Bay," and I assume 「ぬりながら」is "while painting...", but even if I assumed 「ケステンGチンキ」were the name of some kind of paint, or a reference to coloring on the water, I don't really understand what this phrase is trying to convey.

Here's the rest of the paragraph for context:

> この本は、一九八四年一月から月刊「鼓童」に不定期連載されはじめ八五年七月 で一二回（一打）になったー表題の『万里の未知も一打から』と、八二年・三年季刊「鼓童」に載った太鼓の話三編をまとめたものです。ウンコがながめた金魚のお話、最後のページまでお付き合い願えれば幸いです。真野湾沖に三二の漁火を数えた夜、ケステンGチンキをぬりながら・・・佐渡で

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Tincture (herbal medicine), not a paint.  A drummer may need lots of it.

Comment: I did find that translation for 「チンキ」, but how does that go with 「ぬりながら」? And I guess 「ケステンG」would be a brand name, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I googled 「ケステン チンキ」 and found this:

> 浅在性白癬に対するKestenチンキの治験

https://mol.medicalonline.jp/archive/search?jo=ai6yrtyb&ye=1978&vo=6&issue=6

Maybe 「ケステンGチンキ」 is a kind of antifungal medications: cream for tinea.

Comment: I think that's it! I did some more research, and here's what I found:
[This link](http://www.derm-hokudai.jp/shimizu-dermatology/pdf/25-01.pdf) explains 「浅在性白癬」, which I looked up and found to be "tineas superficialis". If you look at that link, bottom of the first page, left side, the column there says that "superficialis" includes "tineas pedis", which is essentially athletes foot. For taiko players, fungal infections like this are pretty common. Tabi, man.

Comment: In that same article, it mentions that [Griseofulvin](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/druginfo/meds/a682295.html) was commonly used, though it is not used as much anymore. I suspect that is what the "G" stands for, as Griseofulvin is used in the treatment of athlete's foot, jock itch, etc. So, I suppose 「ぬる」can also be used for "applying" medicine. How did such a beautiful image of flames out on open water turn so... fungus-y... Anyway, thanks for your help!